# Predicate on property

Tags: c#, list, predicate

I have a `List<B>` and class `B` has a public property `A`.

How can I filter the list of `B` using a `Predicate<A>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your list is named *myList* and your predicate *myPredicate*, then you want probably something like this:

```
var result = myList.Where(b => myPredicate(b.A))
```

or you can use a lambda expression, e.g.:

```
var result = myList.Where(b => b.A < 10)
```

or something like this, where the predicate would be `b.A < 10`.

Maybe you should give us a more complete code sample.

Comment: This is what I was looking for `myList.FindAll(b=>yourPredicate(b.A))` thanks

Comment: function call is more *scallable* then inline lambda

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linq, you can do this:

```
// Define the predicate inline:
var results = list.Where(b => b.A.Name == "Fred");

// or if you have the predicate defined separately:
var results = list.Where(b => predicate(b.A));
```

If you are not using Linq, you can use the FindAll method on the System.Collections.Generic.List class:

```
var results = list.FindAll(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Where(i=>i.B == "something")
```